# Unable to swipe right on ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

I'm using a ViewPager on android.

When I start the ViewPager from a certain position other than 0, I cannot swipe right to go back to previous positions but I can swipe left to go to next positions.

Is it a default ViewPager property ? What do I need to do to be able to swipe right ?

**Inside OnCreate**

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Outside OnCreate**

```
    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return imageFull.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((SubsamplingScaleImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Context context = ImageGallery.this;

            SubsamplingScaleImageView fullImage = 
            new SubsamplingScaleImageView(ImageGallery.this);


           // starting the view pager from position 4 
           viewPager.setCurrentItem(4);
           fullImage.setImage(ImageSource.uri(imageFull.get(position_value)));


            return fullImage;
        }

       @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((SubsamplingScaleImageView) object);

        }
}
```

Comment: No, that is not a default behaviour. It should work as expected, meaning you should be able to move left and right to beginning/end of your items. It might help if you'd add the code of your ImagePagerAdapter.

Comment: I have update the question with the ImagePagerAdapter class

Comment: remove this line `viewPager.setCurrentItem(4);` from adapter class and put it where you initialize viewpager by findViewbyId()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(4);

private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return imageFull.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((SubsamplingScaleImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Context context = ImageGallery.this;

        SubsamplingScaleImageView fullImage = 
        new SubsamplingScaleImageView(ImageGallery.this);



       fullImage.setImage(ImageSource.uri(imageFull.get(position_value)));


        return fullImage;
    }

   @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((SubsamplingScaleImageView) object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. That was the problem. Thanks a ton. I had been struggling with this issue from many days.

Comment: no need to thanks bro this is my Coding is in my DNA, happy to help

Answer (score 3):

You should **setCurrentItem** after setting the adapter for the viewpager not in the viewpager **instantiateItem()** method. You should try this:

**Inside OnCreate**

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(4);
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! I knew it had to be so simple but kept setting the current item before setting the adapter til I read your answer.